# How to handle response which can be different Type in Retrofit 2

Tags: android, json, retrofit2

In WebApi returned JSON's field can be of different class:

```
{ someField:"some string" }
{ someField: { "en" : "some string", "ka" : "რამე სტრინგი" } }
```

I've seen some solutions, but it was on previous versions of Retrofit.

How would my pojo class look like and what can i use to parse this dynamic json?

Comment: Are the keys of the `JSON` dynamic?

Comment: yes it is, it can have different names for different responses. Basicly, every field that is string, can turn into this second type.

Comment: There can be any number of `somefield` and inside that the data can be anything right?

Comment: yes there can be any number of this type of field, but inside that data can only be this two types: String or Object

Comment: Can you tell me that, If "somefield" is an array then is there atleast one field of same name of immediate parent(in this case somefield) ?

Comment: "somefield" is never array. It is string or object/dictionary.

Answer (score 1):

For your case you can use `Call<JsonElement>` as response type and parse it in response:

```
call.enqueue(new Callback<JsonElement>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<JsonElement> call, Response<JsonElement> response) {
            if(response.isSuccessful()){
                JsonElement jsonElement = response.body();
                if(jsonElement.isJsonObject()){
                    JsonObject objectWhichYouNeed = jsonElement.getAsJsonObject();
                } 
                // or you can use jsonElement.getAsJsonArray() method
                //use any json deserializer to convert to your class.
            }
            else{
                System.out.println(response.message());
            }
        }
        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<JsonElement> call, Throwable t) {
            System.out.println("Failed");
        }
    });
```

Comment: problem with this solution is, that i have too many requests, which returns this type of fields every time. so on every call i have to use same code. I want to generalize for every call.