# handle response which has different type in Retrofit 2

Tags: android, json, retrofit2, jsonschema2pojo, gson

Need help with **handling different JSON field types** response in **Retrofit 2**

The serverapi return 2 different types of response and both in Http 200 OK:

**if success,**  server will return this response:
 `{"error_code":"0000","error_message":"success!",item_id:"SHVR25","description":{"DENOMINATION":"25","PRICE":"28000"}}`

**not success,**:
 `{"error_code":"1111","error_message":"failed!",item_id:"SHVR10","description":""}`

**POJO Bill**

```
    public class Bill{

    @SerializedName("error_code")
    @Expose
    public String errorCode;

    @SerializedName("error_message")
    @Expose
    public String errorMessage;

    @SerializedName("item_id")
    @Expose
    public String itemId;

    @SerializedName("description")
    @Expose
    public Description descriptionss;

    public String getErrorCode() {
        return errorCode;
    }

    public void setErrorCode(String errorCode) {
        this.errorCode = errorCode;
    }

    public String getErrorMessage() {
        return errorMessage;
    }

    public void setErrorMessage(String errorMessage) {
        this.errorMessage = errorMessage;
    }

    public String getItemId() {
        return itemId;
    }

    public void setItemId(String itemId) {
        this.itemId = itemId;
    }

    public Description getDescriptionss() {
        return descriptionss;
    }

    public void setDescriptionss(Description descriptionss) {
        this.descriptionss = descriptionss;
    }
    public Description getDescriptionss() {
        return descriptionss;
    }
    }
```

**POJO Description**

```
    public class Description{
    @SerializedName("DENOMINATION")
    @Expose
    public String dENOMINATION;
    @SerializedName("PRICE")
    @Expose
    public String pRICE;


    public String getdENOMINATION() {
        return dENOMINATION;
    }

    public void setdENOMINATION(String dENOMINATION) {
        this.dENOMINATION = dENOMINATION;
    }

    public String getpRICE() {
        return pRICE;
    }

    public void setpRICE(String pRICE) {
        this.pRICE = pRICE;
    }
}
```

**CallBack**

```
    @Override
    public void onResponse(Call<Bill> call, Response<Bill> response) {
        if(response.isSuccessful()){
            Bill bill= response.body();
            Timber.d("bill contains=="+bill.toString());
                            }
        }else{
            Timber.d("response is not success!");}
    }
    @Override
    public void onFailure(Call<JsonElement> call, Throwable t) {
            Timber.e("retrofit failed.... throwable:"+t.toString());
                    }
                }
    );
```

Actually my problem similar to this cases: [How to handle response which can be different Type in Retrofit 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39287515/how-to-handle-response-which-can-be-different-type-in-retrofit-2][1])

**Problem**: call back always called onFailed and said that `java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was STRING at line 1 column 236 path $.description`

**Question**:
 How i can handle different types of response retrofit using POJO as callback not JsonElement, and without changing the server response?

**I have try this**
[How to handle Dynamic JSON in Retrofit?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24279245/how-to-handle-dynamic-JSON-in-retrofit) ( but it works for retrofit 1 ) and [How to handle response which can be different Type in Retrofit 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39287515/how-to-handle-response-which-can-be-different-type-in-retrofit-2) (it using JsonElement as callback response)

Comment: If onFailed is called then there is something wrong with the server response

Comment: Your expected response is Json object but it's returning String?

Comment: Please verify your server response. looks like it is starting with ". retrofit is expecting to start with {.

Comment: @AbhayBohra the difference between 1st response with 2nd response is on description field, one returning json object the other returning string sir.

Comment: @ShylendraMadda i'm expecting both sir but i think the problem is on gson converter. The error occured when gson convert my server response becoming pojo, it's fine with the first response but with the second response was not. because second response returning non String sir.

Comment: @AnkitAman sir yes sir

Comment: @JuliusLaurent You have to tell your backend developer that if description is empty or if error occurs then is should be retuning blank Json Object { }

Comment: @AbhayBohra that can be a solution, but is there another alternative way beside change the response from backend side ?

Comment: try by setting the 'descriptionss' type as Object in Bill class

Comment: @Onkar thanks sir, really appreciate for your help

Comment: @JuliusLaurent   Is it working?

Comment: @Onkar yes it's working now, thank you : )

Comment: @JuliusLaurent  Accept the answer if you satisfied, by clicking Right arrow near the answer post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use **Object** type ,

```
 @SerializedName("description")
  @Expose
  public Object descriptionss;
```

In your Bill class

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you hit the api, there are two possibilities. Success or failure.
To get the error body we use response.errorBody and to parse the error body the kotlin code is written below:

```
val loginRequestError = { response: Response<YourResponse> ->
        SocietyRetrofit.retrofit.responseBodyConverter<Error>(Error::class.java, arrayOf<Annotation>()).convert(response.errorBody())
    }
```

The data class is:

```
data class Error(var error: String, var message: String)
```

The error class contains the fields that your api error contains.

To get the error messsage, we can call the method like this:

```
val errorMessage = loginRequestError(<Your api response>).message
```